# How to pass the value of the selected item from the drop down list as an argument to the Controller (Google charts)?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to get the value of the selected item in the drop down list and then pass that value to MVC controller through `GetChartData`so I can use that value to fetch data from database. I am using google charts to display the data. Here is what I am doing so far:

**Edited**

```
var selectedValue = 0;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input').click(function () {
            selectedValue = $('select option:selected').val();
            drawChart();
        });
    });
```

**End Edited**

```
<form name="regionform" action="">
    <select name="selectregion">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">All Regions</option>
        @foreach (var region in Model.RegionData)
        {
            <option value="@region.regionID"> @region.regionName</option>
        }
    </select>
</form>

.....more code.....

google.load('visualization', '1', { 'packages': ['annotatedtimeline'] });

    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

        $.post('/metrics/GetChartData', { sID: "@Model.SiteId", **regionID : selectedValue** },
        function (data) {

.....code.....

        );
}
```

Comment: I have searched online but I can't find something similar to the kind of problem I am facing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you should be able to just do something like:

```
{ sID: "@Model.SiteId", region: $('#selectregion').val() }
```

You'll need to give your select an id:

```
<select name="selectregion" id="selectregion">
```

'region' will then be available in the form data in your controller.

Comment: Thanks. but it gave me 500 Internal Server Error